# How to programmatically change iPhone settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

It is possible to change iPhone settings from an application?
I want to change settings like enable/disable WIFI, enable/disable vibrations, change ring tone, enable/disable bluetooth, call forwarding, mail accounts, etc. I want to be able to change all settings programmatically. I would appreciate some sample code.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do this unless your application is run on a jailbroken phone.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some of these items programatically on a non-jailbroken phone. Toggling Bluetooth is discussed here, and it's very easy to get working. [Programmatically turn on bluetooth in the iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk)

I am not sure about the other items. Of course you cannot submit this code to the app store, but for personal use it can be very handy.