# Link to BluetoothManager Framework

Tags: iphone, ios4, bluetooth

Please can any one provide me link for BluetoothManager framework which is working properly. I am not able to find any.
Thanxs,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the SO post that answer your Question.

[Programmatically turn on bluetooth in the iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk)

Thanks