# How to interact via Bluetooth to devices other than iOS

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I am struggling with this problem for last 2 days.What I need to do is that i need to transfer data between iPhone and Windows (i.e any other OS, for now i am using Nokia mobile to that). [I have gone through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk). Also I had success in that...

I am able to discover my iPhone in my Nokia device, and when I click "ADD" in Nokia a 6 digit number is sent to iPhone, and here problem starts. I don't know what to do next.

I am using private framework BluetoothManager. Please help me as I am not able to get any documentation on BluetoothManager.framework.

I don't know how to use methods in BluetoothManager.h.

A link to any documentation would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data transfer using your application between iPhone and another phone , you will have to go over SPP profile , in iPhone this is not available to everyone.
You will have to get access to the Apple MFi program to get access to it and it also requires adding an Apple Authentication chip on the device you are trying to connect with.

Comment: I think there is somthing that can be done as i am getting the 6 digit code in my iphone sent by other device ... I just don't know what to do next ... there are method in BluetoothManager.h like connectDevice,connect,pairDevice,detPinFordevice ... I just dont know how to use them ...

Comment: you might be able to pair - thats all I dont think it will connect further