# iOS programatically check if Bluetooth on Mac is connected

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am new to iOS programming and working on a project which needs to detect if an iPod touch(or iPhone 4) is connected to a paired Mac via Bluetooth. I do not need to connect it. I just need to check if it is connected and display a log when it gets disconnected. I do not have Bluetooth LE. Also the app would not be running on the Mac so i cannot create a peer-to-peer connection. Also, i cannot use Bluetooth Manager(or any private framework) since the app would need to be accepted by Appstore at some point of time. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Reading the core blue tooth class reference helps. Here is the link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that so long as the private framework doesn't break any of Apple's guidelines you would be able to use it in your application.  It is only if it DOES break guidelines do you get rejected.  Here is an example of another post on SO suggesting the use of the BluetoothManager Framework.

[How to get the status of bluetooth (ON/OFF) in iphone programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955007/how-to-get-the-status-of-bluetooth-on-off-in-iphone-programatically)

**Edit**:  This slightly covers private APIs vs private frameworks: [Programmatically turn on bluetooth in the iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk)
Another more recent example of someone using BluetoothManager here: [Minimal iOS BluetoothManager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779363/minimal-ios-bluetoothmanager-example)

Comment: Thank you @propstm. If i use Bluetooth Manager as given in http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/#.UUn2phf5Gz4
Then would it be accepted in App store?

Comment: I haven't personally used it, but I cannot see a framework that has evolved as greatly in the past few years at Bluetooth Manager has that it would not be accepted into the app store.  A word on private frameworks, I have included Google's Analytics tracking for iOS and have never had any issues (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/)

Comment: But when i try searching for 'Bluetooth Manager accepted by Appstore' I only get results stating that it will be rejected. So I was a bit apprehensive about using this. Has anyone used it and got the app approved?

Comment: It looks like as of iOS6 some Bluetooth is accessible.  If I had to guess this may be a bit more difficult than BluetoothManager but apple provided code is good check this out http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/39707371281/core-bluetooth-for-ios-6-core-bluetooth-was