# how activate/desactivate the "slide to unlock" on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, security, ipad

All is in the question, i would know if it is possible to activate/desactivate the "slide to unlock " event wich is normally activate/desactive through Settings->General->Passcode Lock

I'm almost certain that we could not play with those setting. I still want to know how we can do that. I suppose we have to use a private framework like some UIView animation, i want to know that for my personal use, it is not an AppStore app project

Comment: On an un-jailbroken iDevice, only the user can modify that setting. Your app cannot.

Comment: I was almost certain that we could not play with those setting. I still want to know how we can do that. I suppose we have to use a private framework like some UIView animation wich use one, i want to know that for my personal use, it is not an AppStore app project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not possible with the public API and an un-jailbroken device. and if your app does that, it will never be accepted to the appstore

Comment: well I am not sure tbh because there is no documented API, but you can for example see how turning on bluetooth works on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk  that MIGHT help a bit

Comment: also you might want to take a look at : http://iphone-dev.googlecode.com/svn/branches/include-1.2-sdk/include/ that might have a certain framework that could solve your problem