# Can I make an app that toggles on and off the iPhone's bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, toggle

I have been looking around for an answer to this, but haven't been able to find anything. Can I toggle on/off my iPhone's bluetooth signal from an app. I hate the process of doing it through the settings app.

I don't have any desire to get this approved through the app store, I just want it for use on my phone (very similar to the Android functionality).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Jeff Broderick made a handy site that lets you add a shortcut icon to your home screen to do this sort of thing. http://brdrck.me/settings/

I use it for Airplane Mode and Wifi. Haven't tried the Bluetooth, but I'd imagine it works as well as the others.