# Existing bluetooth device and Apple MFI

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mfi

I am developing an App which needs to connect to a bluetooth device. I dont want to deploy this app in the app store. I only need this for personal use. Is there any way to connect to this bluetooth device (which is old as hell and definitely not MFI certified). In the FAQ of the MFI program (http://mfi.apple.com/faqs) it says that it is possible with third party solutions. Does anyone know something about that? I havent found any products which builds a bridge between the iPhone and the bluetooth device.

Furthermore the faq says:

"app developers and developers of accessories that rely solely on standard technology (e.g., Bluetooth Low Energy or standard Bluetooth profiles) do not need to join the MFi Program."

My bluetooth device uses a standard bluetooth profile, but i can't connect to it.

Comment: I found this device: http://serialio.com/products/Bluetooth/BlueSnap/BlueSnap_SPP-KEY_Bridge.php. But this device is too big for my use case and the company doesn't have sales partners in europe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is not going to app store, you can try using the private framework called BlueToothManager. I haven't worked with it but it can help you.

The MFI compatible devices are registered with Apple and communicate with a Bluetooth Profile registered with Apple. That particular protocol string (Eg. com.apple.ps1) will be given by the MFI device manufacturer, which you will need to include in the info.plist file.

Comment: Does the BluetoothManager work without a jailbreak? Do you have a link to the framework?

Comment: Yes, it works without a jailbreak, but you cannot submit to appstore as it is a private framework. Here is a post about the framework location http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: also here is an interesting article about the topic: http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=2827

Answer (score -2):

If you are targeting devices which have ios 5 and up you can try using the CoreBluetooth Framework. Here is the link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295

Comment: This only works for Bluetooth LE and I'm sure the OP's device is not LE if it's so old.