# Using CoreBluetooth framework

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I am working on an App which tries to check bluetooth status of iPhone(ON/OFF) using CoreBluetooth framework.I tested app on iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4 devices to check bluetooth status,which do not support bluetooth LE hardware. Then how can i know bluetooth status on iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4 devices through Objective-C.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743610/programmatically-turn-on-bluetooth-in-the-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Using CoreBluetooth, you can get this information via the `centralManagerDidUpdateState:` or `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:` callback, depending on which your device is acting as, a central or a peripheral.

If the device doesn't support BLE, you'll get the `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported` or `CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported` status.
If BLE is turned off for your app, you'll get the `CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized` or `CBPeripheralManagerStateUnauthorized` status.
If Bluetooth is turned off on the device, you'll get the `CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff` or `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff` status.